# Java Generic Misbound

Tags: java, generics, comparable

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;

public interface Comparable<T> {

int compareTo(T other);

}

public class Joueur implements Comparable<Joueur> {

private int points;
private int idJoueur;

public Joueur(int aIdJoueur, int aPoints)
{
    points= aPoints;
    idJoueur = aIdJoueur;
}

public Joueur(int aIdJoueur, int aPoints)
{
    points= aPoints;
    idJoueur = aIdJoueur;
}

public int getIdJoueur()
{
    return idJoueur;
}

public int compareTo(Joueur autre) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (points < autre.points) return -1;
    if (points > autre.points) return 1;
    return 0;
}

public class CollectionJoueur {

ArrayList<Joueur> j = new ArrayList<Joueur>();

public CollectionJoueur(int aIdJoueur, int aPoints)
{
    Joueur ajouterJ = new Joueur(aIdJoueur, aPoints);
    ajouter(ajouterJ);
}
public void ajouter(Joueur joueur)
{
    j.add(joueur);
}

public iterateurJoueur creerIterateur()
{
    Collections.sort(j);

    Iterator<Joueur> itrJoueur = j.iterator();
    while(itrJoueur.hasNext())
    {

    }
}

}
```

So here's my problem, I have been trying to do comparable sort, but in the collections sort it gave me an error of generic misbound. I have a class collection to put the player into the arraylist then i have to sort them out in ascending order.

Comment: Why do you have your own `Comparable` interface?

Answer (score 5):

You should implement java.lang.Comparable interface, not your own Comparable interface.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: You *must* implement `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: @aliteralmind: Must is probably too strong a word, technically you can avoid it by providing a comparator.

Comment: I'm only talking about when a `Comparable` is explicitly requested. In that case, it pretty-much always means the `java.lang.Comparable` version.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that `Collections.sort(..)` is defined as

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
```

In other words, it expects a type that is a sub type of `java.lang.Comparable`. Your class is not a sub type of `java.lang.Comparable`. What you are trying to do with `Collections.sort(..)` is not possible.

Get rid of your `Comparable` type and use `java.lang.Comparable`.

Or write your own sorting method.